# How to set up a OpenGL 4.1 rendering context in OS X Mavericks in c++?

Tags: opengl, sfml, osx-mavericks

I've got a C++ SFML OpenGL 4.1 rendering engine that I want to port to OS X 10.9 Mavericks. SFML does not seem to support OpenGL 4 (or 3) on OS X. What are my options, if I want to stick to c++ (I would prefer avoiding Obj C) to get a rendering context in OS X?

Comment: CGL is the low-level interface you can use in C or C++ to create a render context on OS X. Typically the major frameworks avoid interfacing directly with it and instead write part of the context management for OS X in Objective-C so that they can use classes like `NSOpenGLView`. You cannot use some pretty important parts of Carbon in a 64-bit application either, so a lot of event handling logic has to be written in Objective-C (Cocoa), which is why if you do not like Obj-C (and honestly, *who does?*) you would be better off sticking with a framework than rolling your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) is an excellent cross-platform framework for window and context creation. It supports OpenGL 3.2+